# How to convert back the string object type to tensor object

Tags: python, nlp, tensor, word-embedding

I am working on a csv. I have embedded a column and converted into Tensors. Like,

```
tensor([-1.7110e-01,  1.3811e-01, -2.5881e-01, -1.8281e-01, -3.3073e-01,
    -1.1071e-01])
```

Saved those tensors as a new column and saved that into csv. Now when I load that csv again and see the value of the embedded column it looks like this

```
'tensor([-1.7110e-01,  1.3811e-01, -2.5881e-01, -1.8281e-01, -3.3073e-01,\n        -1.1071e-01])'
```

Let me know how to convert it back and use?

Comment: How do you save and load the tensors? Please include a [mcve] and check [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, what you've written into your CSV file is the `repr` of your tensor object, which is what you see when you print an object. To handle tensors in a CSV file properly, you should serialize your tensor object to the proper data format for export and deserialize it when loading.

Here is an example of how to achieve this:

```py
import csv
import ast

# Sample tensor
sample_tensor = torch.tensor([-1.7110e-01, 1.3811e-01, -2.5881e-01, -1.8281e-01, -3.3073e-01, -1.1071e-01])

# Serialize the tensor as a list and write to CSV
csv_file = 'tensor_data.csv'
with open(csv_file, 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow([sample_tensor.tolist()])

# Read the CSV file and reconstruct the tensor
with open(csv_file, 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    serialized_tensor = next(reader)[0]
reconstructed_tensor = torch.tensor(ast.literal_eval(serialized_tensor))

# Print the reconstructed tensor
print(reconstructed_tensor)
```